TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType' when running Pyinstaller with imports
I am trying to create an executable file from Python, but I receive the errors below. I created a clean environment and tried to reproduce the issue only with imports and a simple print('Hello World') in the file, as can be seen here:
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path
import os
import warnings
from my_functions import launch_tableau_reader
from prime_read_data import prime_read_data
from prime_main_analysis import prime_main_analysis

print('Hello World')

When I removed:
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
import pandas as pd
from my_functions import launch_tableau_reader
from prime_read_data import prime_read_data
from prime_main_analysis import prime_main_analysis

Pyinstaller managed to run without any issues. Below are the errors I receive when I try to run Pyinstaller with all the imports
166 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.9.0, contrib hooks: 2024.7
167 INFO: Python: 3.12.4
189 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
189 INFO: Python environment: C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
191 INFO: wrote C:\Users\guy.lamdan\OneDrive - Playtika Ltd\new_prime\test_exe.spec
192 INFO: Module search paths (PYTHONPATH):
['C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Scripts\\pyinstaller.exe',
 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312',
 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\_vendor',
 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\OneDrive - Playtika Ltd\\new_prime']
414 INFO: checking Analysis
416 INFO: Building because C:\Users\guy.lamdan\OneDrive - Playtika Ltd\new_prime\test_exe.py changed
416 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
416 INFO: Target bytecode optimization level: 0
416 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
417 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
425 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1271 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
1646 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
2158 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
2812 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
2878 INFO: Looking for Python shared library...
2881 INFO: Using Python shared library: C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.dll
2881 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\guy.lamdan\OneDrive - Playtika Ltd\new_prime\test_exe.py
2949 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tkcalendar\calendar_.py:221: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\ '
  font = kw.pop("font", "Liberation\ Sans 9")
3029 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3284 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3481 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4119 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4138 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4150 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4173 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4208 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jaraco.text.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
4298 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\guy.lamdan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 231, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 215, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 70, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1216, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1156, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\OneDrive - Playtika Ltd\new_prime\test_exe.spec", line 4, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
        ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 556, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 696, in assemble
    program_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 268, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super().add_script(pathname)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1160, in add_script
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    ret_modules = super()._safe_import_hook(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1232, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 501, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    ret_modules = super()._safe_import_hook(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1245, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 501, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    ret_modules = super()._safe_import_hook(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1245, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 501, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    ret_modules = super()._safe_import_hook(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1245, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 501, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    ret_modules = super()._safe_import_hook(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1232, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 501, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    ret_modules = super()._safe_import_hook(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1232, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 501, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    ret_modules = super()._safe_import_hook(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1245, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 501, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_hook
    ret_modules = super()._safe_import_hook(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2048, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1232, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 501, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1792, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2591, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 368, in _safe_import_hook
    excluded_imports = self._find_all_excluded_imports(source_module.identifier)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 356, in _find_all_excluded_imports
    excluded_imports.update(module_hook.excludedimports)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 316, in __getattr__
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 383, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 583, in importlib_load_source
    mod_loader.exec_module(mod)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-importlib_resources.py", line 18, in <module>
    if check_requirement("importlib_resources < 1.2.0"):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 414, in check_requirement
    return parsed_requirement.specifier.contains(version, prereleases=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\packaging\specifiers.py", line 914, in contains
    item = Version(item)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guy.lamdan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 198, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'


I was trying to create an executable file from Python using Pyinstaller.

Can you narrow it down more, is the problem with tkinter or pandas or with one of your three custom libraries? If the problem is with your own libraries, what is the contents of these libraries? Can you identify any functions or further imports inside that cause the problem, or is just the fact that you import a custom library triggering the error?

So I actually ended up reinstalling python in a different location and it solved the issue for me.  But to answer your question - I got the same error with each of the imports mentioned in the second code section individually so I couldn't really figure out what was causing this issue
